# Who is speaking in Rev 1:7? The Angel sent in verse 1, John or Jesus?

Tags: revelation, speaker-identification

I'm curious to know who is speaking in Rev 1:7 where is says that every eye will see 'him'. Is it the angel God sends, John himself or Jesus?

Comment: Read from verse 4. John is speaking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  When you have a chance, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how we are  [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than most sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your question, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Answer (score 1):

> Revelation 1:5 To him who loves us and has freed us from our sins by his blood, 6and has made us to be a kingdom and priests to serve his God and Father—to him be glory and power for ever and ever! Amen.
>
> 7“Look, he is coming with the clouds,”
> and “every eye will see him,
> even those who pierced him”;
> and all peoples on earth “will mourn because of him.”
>
> So shall it be! Amen.

Who is speaking in Rev 1:7? The Angel sent in verse 1, John or Jesus?

Nobody is speaking. John is writing and quoting scripture.

He has done this before in
John 19:37

> and, as another scripture says, "They will look on the one they have pierced."

He quotes Zechariah 12:10

> Then I will pour out on the house of David and on the people of Jerusalem a spirit of grace and prayer, and they will **look** on Me, the One they have **pierced**. They will mourn for Him as one mourns for an only child, and grieve bitterly for Him as one grieves for a firstborn son.

If you insist on someone is speaking in Rev 1:7, then it is John.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question let's us look at what it actually say in Revelation Chapter 1 from King James Version (KJV).

1 "The Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave unto him, to showed unto his servants things which must shortly come to pass; and he sent and signified it by his angel unto his servant John."

So verse 7 is John saying all will see him even them who pierced him in the side, just similar to what Jesus told the high priest before his execution in Matthew 26:64 that he would be a witness to authority and his coming too.

Essentially all that is written is done by John who saw and heard what the angel said and showed. Essentially, it would be no different than a reporter telling a story from all perspectives today. The difference is that he got this all from a vision and wrote it as is, as received and as witnessed.

Comment: I don't know why someone would give you a negative vote? Ariel=Lion of God. Revelation 1:4 explicitly says, "John to the seven churches that are in Asia." I know verse 5 says, "and from Jesus Christ etc. But John is the person doing the talking/writing. Notice what John says at Verse 7, "Behold He is coming with the clouds etc. The bottom line is this. The book of Revelation is addressed to the servants (all true believers) and was sent by an angel who made known its truths to His servant John.

Answer (score 0):

The speaker is Jesus. In verses 17-18 John falls at the feet of the one who was speaking and the speakers declares

> “Do not be afraid; I am the first and the last, and the living One;
>   and I was dead, and behold, I am alive forevermore, and I have the
>   keys of death and of Hades."

Answer (score 0):

Determining who is speaking is more difficult than it sounds. The vision of Revelation was shown to at least four people on the mount of transfiguration and their four accounts have been blended together to produce the book of Revelation

edit: But it does seem clear that John is the one speaking